# How do I check browser compatibility for my own JS library?

Tags: javascript, compatibility

I'm making my own Javascript library. It alters placeholders in inputs, which means adding support for < IE9 is pointless. Therefore I'm utilizing `document.querySelectorAll`.

This is a stand-alone library, so I don't want to utilize other libraries such as [Modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/)

Where should I test compatibility for that function and that an input actually supports placeholders?

http://jsfiddle.net/WR3Mr/1/ this is how I've done it so far (see the Javascript window and the comments I've left there). If doing like I've done now, on browsers that don't support these things it'll throw a ReferenceError on the user's script since PHR/PlaceholderRotator wouldn't be defined.

Is this the correct way to do it? Doesn't feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `querySelector()` support using:

```
if('querySelector' in document)
```

Or more simply:

```
if(document.querySelector)
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q276/)

You don't want to cause your script to perform extra work unnecessarily. If the pure function of the library is to act as a shim / shiv for `placeholder` attributes, it'd be better to check whether these attributes are supported and handle them natively before running any more of your library.

Comment: Isn't that the same as `if(document.querySelector)`?

Comment: Did you try? Because I'm really not that good with JavaScript and boolean coercion :-)

Comment: Check my jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/WR3Mr/). This is not really my question (sorry if I asked it badly). What would be the best approach to place that check for these things? At the top of the IIFE (like I've done now) - which will render `PHR` and `PlaceholderRotator` as undefined - or inside the script when actually doing these things?

Comment: And the big difference from `if ( typeof document.querySelectorAll === 'undefined' )` is ..? (besides querySelectorAll is the big issue reg browsersupport here)

Comment: @BenM So I should place these checks within the constructor? Then when running functions such as run(), which expects the selector to be a valid NodeList, other errors will occur. Do I need to place a check in every public function?

Comment: Just write it to a `boolean` inside your constructor, and check its value in functions?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is:

```
var foo;
if(document.querySelector) {
  foo = document.querySelector;
} else {
  foo = function() {
     ...code which emulates document.querySelector...
  }
}
```

After that, you just call `foo()`.

The main advantage to this approach is that you usually have an idea what you need to be done. So it makes sense to create a function for this which is specifically geared towards your needs. Then you can use this function in many places. If something is wrong, you need to fix it only on one (or two) places. Using the function switch above, you don't need expensive `if()` constructs - just call the function; when you can, it's ready to serve.

Comment: How about a try-catch? Like so; `try { document.querySelectorAll(); } catch(e){}`? I'm not gonna polyfill querySelectorAll since all browsers which supports placeholder attr supports querySelectorAll.

Comment: try catch is nice if you need this only once. For frameworks, you need helper functions that are used in many places. So the goal is to make the places where this pattern is used concise and spend more effort in the place where it's defined.

Comment: Yeah but in this case it's a small library that's only gonna alter the placeholder attribute. This means that browsers that don't support `querySelectorAll` doesn't support placeholders either. Correct? Which means that I can just let browsers that don't support `querySelectorAll` run into the empty `catch`.

Comment: @WillB: Your question doesn't make sense. I'm not taking about IE 9 vs. IE 10. I'm talking about how to write JS frameworks in general. Also, you shouldn't assume that feature X depends on feature Y. There might be a version of some browser where this isn't true (or not always true). Which is why you should check each feature individually and implement a workaround when it's not there. The mess we had with IE6 proved for all time that browser switches are pure evil.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm new to all of this so some things I do maybe not makes sense :D. Is https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/polyfill.js#L671 this a good polyfill for it? Also, I'm gonna need to use `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`, both which aren't supported in IE8. It all feels so pointless since it won't show placeholders anyway.

Comment: Then use an empty emulation function. The goal is that the client code (ie. anything using your framework) doesn't need to care; it just calls your function and "it just works".

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WR3Mr/2/ It seems to work but it seems a bit too "hacky", not sure if I understood you :D?